# C# Task в главном потоке и фоновое состояние

Tags: c#, .net-6

Есть пример с [AwaitOperator](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

Который я запускаю под .NET 6.0

Почему при выполнении кода:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
Task<int> downloading = DownloadDocsMainPageAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} " +
    $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground} " +
    $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} main: Launched downloading.");

int bytesLoaded = await downloading;
Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} " +
    $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground} " +
    $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} main: Downloaded {bytesLoaded} bytes.");

static async Task<int> DownloadDocsMainPageAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground} " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} " +
        $"{nameof(DownloadDocsMainPageAsync)}: About to start downloading.");

    var client = new HttpClient();
    byte[] content = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/");

    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground} " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} " +
        $"{nameof(DownloadDocsMainPageAsync)}: Finished downloading.");
    return content.Length;
}
```

Я получаю результат:

```
MainThread False 1 DownloadDocsMainPageAsync: About to start downloading.
MainThread False 1 main: Launched downloading.
 True 8 DownloadDocsMainPageAsync: Finished downloading.
 True 8 main: Downloaded 132518 bytes.
```

Который мне сообщает, что:

1. Из главного потока я перешёл в `DownloadDocsMainPageAsync`
2. И в `DownloadDocsMainPageAsync` я всё ещё нахожусь главным потоком и делаю асинхронность `GetByteArrayAsync` но окончание результата я уже получаю в другом фоновом потоке из пула потоков
3. В метод `main` я возвращаюсь тем же фоновым потоком из пула потоков.

Вопросы:

1. Куда делся мой главный поток? Почему работа программы продолжается в потоке из пула потоков?
2. Почему работа программы продолжается в фоновом потоке, а не в нормальном, который изначальном инициировал Task?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:** немного упростил

Но если сделать так

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>Work1());

Console.WriteLine(new
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
});

SynchronizationContext sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
await t;
sc.Send((o) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(new
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    });
},null);

Console.WriteLine(new
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
});

static void Work1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(new
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    });
}
```

Чтобы попытаться якобы попасть в `SynchronizationContext`, но он оказывается `NULL` в консольном приложении.

Вообще, это страшно или не страшно, что после асинхронности поток продолжается из фонового потока? Из моих знаний, фоновые потоки - это потоки не имеющие приоритета и в случае завершения программы, они не будут дожидаться окончания.

Если первый пример запустить отладкой и посмотреть на потоки, то `MainThread` описан как `Приложение перешло в состояние останова, но отсутствует код для вывода на экран, так как все потоки исполняли внешний код (как правило, системный код или код платформы).`. Это же плохо для штатной дальнейшей работы если я не собираюсь завершать программу, а дальше будут из потока из пула потоков строить вызовы?!

Comment: Task<int> downloading = await DownloadDocsMainPageAsync();

Comment: @Konst даже не скомпилируется, и к чему этот совет - непонятно.

Comment: согласен, не внимательно посмотрел

Answer (score 1):

Потому что так работает оператор await: продолжение асинхронного метода вызывается в том же потоке, который завершил задачу, если только нет дополнительный указаний, вроде флага RunContinuationsAsynchronously или установленного контекста синхронизации.

Вы начали сетевой запрос в потоке 1, но завершился он в потоке 8 (это нормально для асинхронного кода!). Поскольку контекста синхронизации установлено не было - в том же потоке 8 были вызваны продолжения сначала DownloadDocsMainPageAsync, а потом Main.

То, что у вас работа продолжается в фоновых потоках - совершенно нормально. Если вы опасаетесь что программа завершится раньше времени - то она не завершится пока не завершится задача, которую вы вернули из асинхронного Main. Там на самом деле компилятор сгенерировал блокирующее ожидание, что-то вроде вот такого кода:

```cs
private static void $GeneratedMain() => Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Вот вызов GetResult - и есть тот самый внешний код, который исполняется в потоке MainThread.

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время на разъяснение! Про `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` - я так понял это свойство определяет только требование на продолжение работы в другом потоке, а не в клиентском потоке до вызова `await`?! Т.к. у меня все 3 ID потока получились разные (главный, асинхрон, продолжение). Про контекст вы сделали хорошее замечание, но к сожалению у меня в консольном приложении не получилось его поймать и правильно вернуть. Наверно его нет? Подробности в вопросе добавил.

Comment: @KUL ну разумеется контекста синхронизации у вас нет, откуда он вообще возьмётся в консольном приложении и зачем он там?

Comment: `Другой аспект SynchronizationContext — у каждого потока есть «текущий» контекст.` [Концепция SynchronizationContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-synchronizationcontext) тогда я ничего не понимаю ...

Comment: @KUL у каждого потока *может быть* текущий контекст. В данном случае его нет, потому что его никто не устанавливал.

Comment: @KUL если вы желаете использовать контекст синхронизации - вам надо его написать и установить, а не просто проверить Current и ожидать что там что-то будет